# c++ Why is ifstream get() function returning unrecognized special characters?

Tags: c++, string, file, vector, locale

I am trying to implement a class Text in c++ that loads a text file (.txt), searches every character in that file and stores all the words and all the delimiters (delimiter in this case would be everything that isn't a character) in two respective vectors (`#include <vector>`). Since the text file main contain special characters, I've set the locale for the program using `setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8")`.

As the code below executes (being the constructor of the class text), I've noticed that after the ifstream class is constructed and the code enters the `while` loop, the `char c`, which I've stored using `arch.get(c)`, contains an unrecognized caracter (this bad boy right here: ▒).

In this case of `c` being special character, it will be saved on a string (`string d`) and with the next loop, if a letter (identified by the `isalpha(c)`) shows up at the file, it stores the `string d` on the respective delimiter vector. The same logic applies for the letters, as they are saved on `string p` and then saved on the words vector (*words = palavras* in english). The part where I'm the most confused is when I print `string d` and check its value, the recognized special character from the file appears correctly.

**Why is the special character only recognizable if I insert it in a `string`? Why is the `arch.get(c)` function returning an unrecognized char?**

The following code is the constructor of the class `Text`. The prints for testing have comments for indication.

```
Text::Text( string na ) {
    // Inicialization of variables
    total_size = 0;
    word_first_flag = false;
    namearch = na;
    string p = "";
    string d = "";
    vector<string>::iterator it_delim;
    it_palavras = palavras.begin();
    it_delim = delim.begin();

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8");

    ifstream arch(namearch);

    char c;

    while(arch.get(c)) {
        if(total_size > 10000)
            break;

            cout << c << endl; // Prints ▒

        switch (isalpha(c)) { // does not recognize special characters
            case 0:
                if(p == "") {
                    d = d + c;
                    cout << "-" << d << "-"<< endl; // Prints correct char
                }
                else {
                    Palavra paux;
                    paux = p;
                    palavras.push_back(paux);
                    p = "";
                    d = d + c;
                }
            break;
            default:
                if(total_size == 0) word_first_flag = true;

                if(d == "") {
                    p = p + c;
                }
                else {
                    delim.push_back(d);
                    cout << "-" << d << "-" << " Inserted!" << endl << endl; // Also prints correct char
                    d = "";
                    p = p + c;
                }
            break;
            }

            ++total_size;
        }
    }

    if(d != "")
        delim.push_back(d);

    it_palavras = palavras.begin();
    arch.close();
}
```

According to the documentation of the `locale` class, everything should work normally for the special character. But that's not the case. I've also tried to insert the c in a string but it just saves the faulty character. I could change all the types for `wstrings` and `wchat_t` but the locale setting apparently already does that, according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/

> In C++, locales are represented by an object of the locale class. Each
>   of these locale objects contains all the information needed to use a
>   set of culture-dependent features.

I'm compiling on `gcc` 6.4.0 version on the Cygwin. I'm also aware that I could use the `gdb` for debugging but at this stage it wouldn't help much.

Comment: The character you see is likely a leading byte in a multi-byte encoding, probably UTF-8. It doesn't make sense in isolation, only in combination with the rest of multi-byte sequence.

Comment: But since I've set the locale, shouldn't the character always be a multi-byte?

Comment: I don't believe locale has any effect when reading `char`s from a `char`-based stream. It just gives you the stream's bytes as-is. The answer might change if you were using a wide stream, e.g. `wifstream`. Also, I wonder if `setlocale`call even succeeds  - `"portuguese-brazilian"` doesn't look like a valid locale name to me. Check the function's return value.

Comment: Yes, the call for `"portuguese-brazilian"` returned `null`. I'll be correcting it in the question. Now `printf ("Locale is: %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_BR.UTF-8") );` prints the locale I wanted.
Changing to `wifstream` however doesn't seem to work. It gives the following error:
_` invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::basic_istream<wchar_t>::char_type& {aka wchar_t&}’ from an rvalue  of type ‘std::basic_istream<wchar_t>::char_type {aka wchar_t}`_
Is tis occuring because of the wrong size of chars?

Comment: You'd of course also need to change `char c;` to `wchar_t c;`

Comment: And adding ``w`` to every single ``string`` and ``cout`` and ``cin`` and others, right?

Comment: Well, yes, if you want to deal with Unicode characters. Calling `isalpha` on individual bytes is pointless unless the data is pure ASCII. Speaking of which - you would also need `iswalpha`

Comment: The data is pure ASCII to a maximum value of 255. So making everything accept multi-byte encoding would still be pointless?

Comment: Are you sure? From your description, it sounds like some multi-byte encoding, probably UTF-8. That's not ASCII. It's of course pointless to look at individual bytes of a multi-byte sequence - to understand what character it represents, you need to examine the whole sequence, e.g. by converting it to a Unicode codepoint.

Comment: I've made a test code to understand the values of the characters, just to make sure how this encoding works.I've assigned `wchar_t c = 'é'`. The `iswalpha(c)` seems to work, but when I print `c`, it shows `쎩`. How can the program understand the correct character then?

Comment: Try `wchar_t c = L'é';`, or `wchar_t c = L'\u00E9';` With the former, the outcome might change depending on how, in what encoding, your source file is saved; the latter is more portable.

Comment: It works, the `é` is printed! Now I'll make the correct adjustments for the Text class and check if it works too.

Answer (score 0):

So with very helpful insight by @Igor Tandetnik and some testing with these types of data, I've changed the original code so that it correctly takes the special characters from the archive.

```
Text::Text( string na ) {
// Inicialization of variables
total_size = 0;
word_first_flag = false;
namearch = na;
wstring p = L"";
wstring d = L"";
vector<wstring>::iterator it_delim;
it_palavras = palavras.begin();
it_delim = delim.begin();

setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8");

wifstream arch(namearch);

wchar_t c;

while(arch.get(c)) {
    if(total_size > 10000)
        break;

        wcout << c << endl;

    switch (iswalpha(c)) {
        case 0:
            if(p == L"") {
                d = d + c;
                wcout << "-" << d << "-"<< endl;
            }
            else {
                Palavra paux;
                paux = p;
                palavras.push_back(paux);
                p = L"";
                d = d + c;
            }
        break;
        default:
            if(total_size == 0) word_first_flag = true;

            if(d == L"") {
                p = p + c;
            }
            else {
                delim.push_back(d);
                wcout << "-" << d << "-" << " Inserted!" << endl << endl;
                d = L"";
                p = p + c;
            }
        break;
        }

        ++total_size;
    }
}

if(d != L"")
    delim.push_back(d);

it_palavras = palavras.begin();
arch.close();
}
```

In short, the adjustments to the code were:

1. Change all the `char`, `string` and iostream for their multi-byte format (for example:`wchar_t`, `wstring` and `wcout`);
2. Adding `L` before every char or string ( `L''` or `L""`) to make the multi-byte convertion.